# How does NetSuite store customised form layouts?

Tags: netsuite

If I make a change to the layout of a form in NetSuite, does anyone know how NetSuite internally stores this customisation?  I appreciate this is down to the internal implementation of NetSuite, but am interested nonetheless to understand how it works.

For example, say I amend the contact screen to rearrange fields or maybe hide some of the default fields.

Does NetSuite store this customisation in the database, or is it stored as some type in configuration file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NetSuite's underlying database architecture is Oracle however you do not have access to it.